# Animate Real Snow Add-on

Tags: animation, add-on

I'm fairly new in Blender and I'm trying to animate the coverage/height of the Real Snow Add-On. It worked the first time I added the snow, but sadly it doesn't
anymore ever since. Is anyone having an idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, Denise, and welcome. We've got very little / nothing to go on, here.. Did you save a version that worked?  Can you clue us in to your settings? Maybe share a version, stripped down as far as possible. on https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: No, I couldn't save anything, as I wanted to redo it and then found out, it only worked the first time. Maybe it was also some kind of malfunction/glitch.